# NSCopying Protocol Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to implement a test of 20 questions in Swift, the same viewcontroller should be repeat each time the next button is pressed until the last question but this creates a queue of viewcontrollers this should not happen . I was reading and NSCopying Protocol could help me but I can't understand totally in which way. Someone could explain me or give an example of the correct way to use of NSCopying protocol to this case

Comment: You don't want to use `NSCopying` for this.  If you don't want to push on a new view controller for each question then just change the view of the current question's view controller to show the next question.

Comment: What does the `NSCopying` protocol have to do with pushing too many view controllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS each "screen" is usually represented by a single ViewController which can customise it's view and handle the interaction with the user.

NSCopying is used to make copies of objects but it's probably not what you need here as it should be the same controller handling all the questions

In your case you should have let's say a QuestionsViewController with probably a "next button".

```
class QuestionsViewController: UIViewController {}
```

Then, you link the touchUpInside action of your button to a IBAction method (if you use Interface Builder for building your view) in QuestionsViewController and update the view to change the question label and reset the answer field(s)

```
@IBAction func nextQuestion(sender: UIButton) {
    // Update the view...
}
```

Alternatively you could use a UIpageViewController / UItableView / UIcollectionView where each question would be different view / cell

You can have a look at theses tutorials :

[Handling user action tutorial](http://codewithchris.com/xcode-tutorial-user-interaction/)

[Quizz video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nvug6a_jPRs)

[PageViewController tutorial](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/12/23/swift-uipageviewcontroller-tutorial/)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, this was what I was looking for

Comment: @SheyVC IF this solves your issue then you should accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead creating different viewcontroller for each question ,you can use single viewcontroller and on next change the question.You can use UIView animation for moving from one question to another.